# How to read a value from the previous dense rank of the row in Python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply, lookup

i have table.csv:

```
ID,X,X_2,X_3,Rank
XJ5,30,24,37,1
XK4,20,22,20,1
XK5,33,27,38,1
XK7,22,19,22,1
XJ5,33,22,21,2
XK4,20,22,22,2
XK5,33,24,29,2
XK6,23,21,22,2
XJ5,24,22,19,3
XK4,21,20,34,3
XK5,19,22,32,3
XK6,44,24,21,3
XK7,32,21,23,3
```

and want to output table:

```
ID,X,X_2,X_3,Rank,PrevX
XJ5,30,24,37,1,NA
XK4,20,22,20,1,NA
XK5,33,27,38,1,NA
XK7,22,19,22,1,NA
XJ5,33,22,21,2,30
XK4,20,22,22,2,20
XK5,33,24,29,2,33
XK6,23,21,22,2,NA
XJ5,24,22,19,3,33
XK4,21,20,34,3,20
XK5,19,22,32,3,33
XK6,44,24,21,3,23
XK7,32,21,23,3,NA
```

The new PrevX column is the X value of the ID from Rank-1 row

here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('table.csv')
```

Comment: can you clarify this rule *is the X value of the ID from Rank-1* ?

Comment: It is the X value from the ID's previous rank (Rank-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

One way is to:

1. Group the data per `id` using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) apply for each group the following:
2. Order by `rank` using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
3. Create a temporary columns where `rank` are shifted by one using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)
4. Add `1` to this new columns using [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)
5. Compare this new column with the `rank` column using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): if they are equal, assign the previous `X` value, else, assign `NaN`
6. Optional to match expected output:

   - remove useless column with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
   - reset index with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
   - sort by `rank` using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Here the code:

```
def get_previous(df):
    df = df.sort_values(by="Rank")
    df["rank_shifted"] = df.Rank.shift().add(1)
    df["PrevX"] = np.where(df.rank_shifted == df.Rank, df.X.shift(), np.NaN)
    return df

df = df.groupby('ID').apply(get_previous)
print(df)
#         ID   X  X_2  X_3  Rank  rank_shifted  PrevX
# ID
# XJ5 0  XJ5  30   24   37     1           NaN    NaN
#     3  XJ5  33   22   21     2           2.0   30.0
#     6  XJ5  24   22   19     3           3.0   33.0
# XK4 1  XK4  20   22   20     1           NaN    NaN
#     4  XK4  20   22   22     2           2.0   20.0
#     7  XK4  21   20   34     3           3.0   20.0
# XK5 2  XK5  33   27   38     1           NaN    NaN
#     5  XK5  33   24   29     2           2.0   33.0
#     8  XK5  19   22   32     3           3.0   33.0

# Match output
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(by="Rank").drop("rank_shifted", axis=1)
print(df)
#     ID   X  X_2  X_3  Rank  PrevX
# 0  XJ5  30   24   37     1    NaN
# 3  XK4  20   22   20     1    NaN
# 6  XK5  33   27   38     1    NaN
# 1  XJ5  33   22   21     2   30.0
# 4  XK4  20   22   22     2   20.0
# 7  XK5  33   24   29     2   33.0
# 2  XJ5  24   22   19     3   33.0
# 5  XK4  21   20   34     3   20.0
# 8  XK5  19   22   32     3   33.0
```

#### Original answer

Assuming the rank are always composed by 3 rows, you can use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df["PrevX"] = df.X.shift(3)
print(df)
#     ID   X  X_2  X_3  Rank  PrevX
# 0  XJ5  30   24   37     1    NaN
# 1  XK4  20   22   20     1    NaN
# 2  XK5  33   27   38     1    NaN
# 3  XJ5  33   22   21     2   30.0
# 4  XK4  20   22   22     2   20.0
# 5  XK5  33   24   29     2   33.0
# 6  XJ5  24   22   19     3   33.0
# 7  XK4  21   20   34     3   20.0
# 8  XK5  19   22   32     3   33.0
```

If you don't know the number of row per `rank` group, you can find it with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print(df.groupby('Rank').size())
# Rank
# 1    3
# 2    3
# 3    3
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: the rank will not always be composed by 3 rows as some IDs wont always have entries and new IDs are added as well

Comment: So what is the rule to chose them ? For example, if you have 4 rows for `rank 1` and 3 rows for `rank 2`, how do you chose the rows in rank 2 ?

Comment: should look up the value for the ID at rank-1, if it doesn't exist then NA. I've edited my question

Comment: Thank you for the details, the update takes this into account.

Comment: what if I wanted to get the value from Rank-2, Rank-3... Rank-n?

Comment: What do you mean? The function works whatever the number of ranks is.

Comment: What if for Rank 3 I wanted to return Rank 1's value instead of Rank 2?

Comment: Oh, this is another question. You need to change to selection criteria in `get_previous`. The default `shift` behaviour is one (e.g. select the previous rank). If you want a bigger gap (e.g. 3), you can replace all `shift()` by `shift(2)`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think of `groupby` and `shift`  as follows:
_ `groupby` on `Rank` and find `diff` is `1` to create a mask `m` to identify which `ID` has value base on condition their `Rank` is adjacent (Rank-1). Any same `ID` within Rank-1 will be flag `True`, otherwise `False`
_ `groupby` on `ID` and `shift` on `X`
_ Finally, use `where` with mask `m` to flip those `False` in `m` to `NaN`

```
m = df.groupby('ID').Rank.diff().eq(1)
df['prevX'] = df.groupby('ID').X.shift().where(m)

Out[28]:
     ID   X  X_2  X_3  Rank  prevX
0   XJ5  30   24   37     1    NaN
1   XK4  20   22   20     1    NaN
2   XK5  33   27   38     1    NaN
3   XK7  22   19   22     1    NaN
4   XJ5  33   22   21     2   30.0
5   XK4  20   22   22     2   20.0
6   XK5  33   24   29     2   33.0
7   XK6  23   21   22     2    NaN
8   XJ5  24   22   19     3   33.0
9   XK4  21   20   34     3   20.0
10  XK5  19   22   32     3   33.0
11  XK6  44   24   21     3   23.0
12  XK7  32   21   23     3    NaN
```